# number of stickers in iMessage

Tags: ios, imessage, imessage-extension

Is there any restriction on the number of stickers we can use in iMessage app? I know we should keep sticker size less than 500KB but that's for individual sticker. What about the total size of all the stickers?

Comment: I think there is no limit on the number of stickers, you can add as you can

Comment: check this, there is not mentioned anything about the number of stickers. Just size is mentioned.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages

Comment: I have added 171 stickers and when i scroll them a few times then it get starts hanging. Animation get stopped and jerks while scroll.

Comment: where are you scrolling? you scrolling all stickers when trying to choose a sticker to send, or have you sent 171 in a message?

Comment: yes while scrolling all stickers when trying to choose a sticker to send

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things we need to make sure.

Display size of each sticker should be minimum 100x100 points. And maximum should be 206x206 points.

I was using custom way of presenting the stickers using `UIColelctionView` and cell size was 73x73 which causes 4 stickers per row.

I changes the size to 100x100 and it started appear 3 stickers in 1 row and everything started working fine. No hang or stuck issue after that.